# Implementing select2 in form to query existing users, ModelMultipleChoiceField is always invalid on form

Tags: python, html, django, forms

I inherited a project where we wanted to use django's native User model but also give users some additional fields. So I made a model called `UserProfiles`, which has a foreignkey to each User instance. I made a template to update these `UserProfiles` called `settings-userprofile.html`. Previously, we only had the field `api_key` for people to modify, so things were basic.

We want every User to have their own list of "assistant" Users, a label relevant for an API we'll be implementing. So I added the field `assistants` and updated `settings-userprofile.html` to include a `<select multiple>` element that lists out all the existing users on our site. We're using a theme/template that is able to implement the select2 pillbox/tokenization element (like the rightmost screencap in this picture)

[image]

user_profile/models.py

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    phone_number    = models.CharField(max_length=15, verbose_name='Phone Number')
    user            = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    api_key         = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='12345678',)
    assistants = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="assistants")
```

settings-userprofile.html

```
    <form class='form-horizontal' method="post" action="{% url 'profileUpdate' %}">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="form-group row mb-4">
            <label for="api_key" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label"><b>Profile Api Key:</b></label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
              <input type="text" name="api_key" class="form-control" id="horizontal-apikey-input" value="{{ request.user.userprofile.api_key }}">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">User list</label>

            <select name="assistants" class="select2 form-control select2-multiple" multiple="multiple" data-placeholder="Choose ...">
                <optgroup label="Existing users">
                    {% for u in allUsers %}
                    {% if u in request.user.userprofile.assistants %}
                    <option selected value="{{ u.username }}">{{ u.username }}</option>
                    {% else %}
                    <option value="{{ u.username }}">{{ u.username }}</option>
                    {% endif %}
                    {% endfor %}
                </optgroup>
            </select>
        </div>

         <div class="form-group row justify-content-end">
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                <div>
                    <button type="submit" name='apikey_submit' class="btn btn-primary w-md">Submit</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

user_profile/views.py

```
from .forms import UserProfileForm
@login_required
def display_settings_page(request):
    form = UserProfileForm(instance=request.user)
    allUsers = User.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'settings-userprofile.html', { 'form':form, 'allUsers':allUsers })

@login_required
def settings_update_profile(request):
    allUsers =  User.objects.all()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        old_api = request.user.userprofile.api_key
        form = UserProfileForm(data=request.POST, instance=request.user.userprofile)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, "Your API key was changed from " + old_api + " to " + form.cleaned_data["api_key"])
            return render(request, 'settings-userprofile.html', {'form': form, 'allUsers':allUsers})
        else:
            print(form.errors)
            return render(request, 'settings-userprofile.html', {'form': form, 'allUsers':allUsers})
    # omitting the rest of this code since it only applies to GET requests
```

In forms.py, we represented assistants using `forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField` and specified the queryset as the set of all Users.

user_profile/forms.py

```
class UserProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    api_key = forms.CharField(required=False)
    assistants = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(required=False,
        queryset=User.objects.all(),
    )
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ['api_key', 'assistants']
```

This got me as far as to a point where I see a dropdown menu that lists out all the users on my site, and I can select 1 or more users. usernames and emails are the same on this application, so I see a list of emails as intended.

In the view function, I can use `print(request.POST.getlist('assistants'))` and it prints a list of the tokenized usernames selected in the dropdown menu on submission.

However, is_valid() is always failing and I'm not sure how to go about fixing it. For instance, we have a user registered at the email/username devtest4@gmail.com . Selecting them and Printing form.errors reveals...

```
<ul class="errorlist">
     <li>assistants
     <ul class="errorlist"><li>“devtest4@gmail.co
m” is not a valid value.</li></ul>
     </li>
</ul>
```

The username still isn't being treated as a valid value, despite the fact that the queryset is specified to be a list of all users.

Comment: If you're trying to do this because you want to learn from it, then great. But otherwise, your time is/would've been better spent using [DAL](https://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.io/en/master/tutorial.html) or [Django-select2](https://django-select2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Comment: @Melvyn I'm working on a site and trying to get more comfortable with django for simple things. Rn I feel like form validation is harder for me than it should be. I was just trying to use the html code as is because it had the styling that we wanted/involved the least modifications to our website template/theme. Might be worth looking into custom styling on DAL.

Comment: Gotcha. So, relationship fields expect primary keys as values. You're sending email addresses. So your option value should be user.pk.